# how to use JDBC 4 driver with oracle 11?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver

I am using oracle 11g . I do not know what is the default driver comes with oracle 11g. I see `ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0` under my  `<TOMCAT_HOME>/lib`. I am not sure what change i need to do to make sure i am using JDBC 4 driver ?

Do i need to replace `ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0` or i need to put some other jar under my oracle installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcvers.htm#BCFFIFAD), Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1) goes with JDBC drivers provide support for the JDBC 4.0 standard.
You should have the *ojdbc6.jar* in your classpath environment variable in order to have JDBC 4.0 standard support.

Take a look at Oracle's JDBC drivers [list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-111060-084321.html): for 11g and 11g2, only *ojdbc5.jar* and *ojdbc6.jar* are listed, but some says that *ojbc14* should work just fine with Oracle11g. 
The primary difference between *ojbc14* and later versions is that it wouldn't support new JDBC API, so I suppose you should better go with newer drivers.

Comment: so just replacement of `ojdbc14.jar` with  `ojdbc6.jar`  is required. is it ?

Comment: Refer to the Oracle FAQ for more details.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03